# Cannot find a valid mapping for user#id which is causing a runtime error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i am trying to set reset password for my application by following the tutorial at [Railscast Reset password tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Uyf.jpg) and everything went well until the last step after clicking the reset password link in the mail , so when i update the password it is telling "RuntimeError in PasswordResetsController#update" caused due to "Could not find a valid mapping for #

you can check out the error in more detail in the screen shot below . and also i had a migration error at the start of the process while i was trying to migrate the reset_password into the users table ,it said remember_token table already exists so skipping it ,do u think it had any thing to do with the error.

would really like to know what i am doing wrong , thank u...
[Unfortunately my reputation is not high enough to post images so i have posted links of the images in order , dont mind.]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPNIv.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbOFR.png]

Comment: does it raise on `sign_in @user`? I don't see where exactly error raises

Comment: well when i reset the password , when it calls the sign_in @user ,it shows this error saying ,the user cannot be mapped to a valid user represnting the token

Comment: i guess, problem in sign_in method.
is it method of gem 'devise'? or it's yours?

Comment: Follow all the steps properly again. In episode you don't have any sign_in method. This kind of reset password present in devise. But you are not using that. Also You are using remember_token this is also not present in episode you are following. Try to follow one methodology at once.

Comment: like the application base is build on michael hartl tutorial , and in past it did work out but is was a long time ago, dont know whr am going wrong.So because of which its kind of mix of two ,but the authentication method is similar right.

Answer (score 0):

Make the link to reset the password as

```
localhost:3000/password_resets?remember_token=abcdefghikfhgj
```

In password_resets_controller.rb:-

```
def edit
  @user = User.find_by_remember_token(params[:remember_token])
end

def update
  @user = User.find_by_remember_token(params[:remember_token])
  #other codes
end
```

Comment: when i do this i am getting an error                                     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PasswordResetsController#edit , saying  "Couldn't find User with remember_token = "

Comment: check in console that the remember_token value is there and is matches the same passed in the url

Comment: i have checked in the console the link is still "http://localhost:3000/password_resets/Sfmx0a95rxi2C2h4xsnuzQ/edit
" , not like u had suggested earlier , no it is not takin the token it is just displaying " http://localhost:3000/password_resets/4/edit" , even though when i place the link with token it is displaying the same error